# Wiring multiple photoelectric sensors to RPI 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, wiring, light-sensor

[image]I am relatively new to using Raspberry Pis and wiring sensors. I am trying to wire the PM-U25 photoelectric sensor to a Raspberry Pi 4 to act as an optical resolver that tracks a shutter wheel on a rotating motor. When I wire 1 sensor (+V to an external power source, -V to an external power source, Light ON to GPIO, Dark ON to GPIO) it works perfectly fine and I can read the output (I am only using the Light ON, so I technically don't need the Dark ON. But I've noticed I only get outputs with both plugged in...? Leaving only one connected to the RPI gives me no signal). However, when I wire both sensors up in the same manner (2 outputs to RPI), I don't detect any output from either sensor. Does anyone have a suggestion or know how I should be wiring up the sensors to the RPIs? Do I need to somehow connect the dark ON wires together?

Here is a link to the photoelectric sensor I'm using. The electrical schematic is on page 10 in the top right corner: https://www.onlinecomponents.com/en/datasheet/pmu25-49373297/

Thanks! Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDITS: I've attached a photo of my setup and a code snippet.

```
void motorController::initializeRoll()
{
    qDebug() << "Initialize roll() called!";
    QString motorUsed = "roll";
    setDirection(clockwise, directionPinNegRoll, directionPinPosRoll);
    gpioSetMode(sensorPinWRoll, 1);
    gpioSetMode(sensorPinRoll, 0);

    //gpioSetMode(15, 0);
    //gpioSetMode(14, 1);


    serverSocket rollInitializeErrorNotifier;
    QString data;
    rollSteps = 0;

    bool initSuccess = false;
    float initSpeed = getSpeed(3);
    int sensorRead;
    //int sensorReadb;
    int consecutiveZeroScan=0;
    int consecutiveOneScan=0;
    int minimumFlagLength = 2.83*gearRatio;//8*gearRatio; //8 for 400smooth (step/rev)
    int maximumFlagLength = 5.194*gearRatio;//Too many scans means something is wrong with sensor. //12 for 400 smooth
    int consecutiveZeroThreshold = 2.3611*gearRatio; //How many scans until we decide sensor isn't detecting anything. //10 for 400 smooth
    int maxOneCount = 0;
    int maxZeroCount = 0;
    int initializeStepsBeforeGiveUp = 1.2*stepsPerRev*gearRatio;


    for (int i = 0; i < initializeStepsBeforeGiveUp; i++) {
        sensorRead = gpioRead(sensorPinWRoll);
        //sensorReadb = gpioRead(sensorPinRoll);

        qDebug() << "sensorReadWhite value AT START is: " << sensorRead;
        //qDebug() << "sensorReadBlack value AT START is: " << sensorReadb;
        qDebug() << "MaxOneCOUNT is :                 " << maxOneCount;
        qDebug() << "MaxZeroCOUNT is :                 " << maxZeroCount;



        if (sensorRead == 1) { //sensor detection.

            consecutiveZeroScan=0;

            while (sensorRead == 1) {
                consecutiveOneScan++;
                qDebug() << "ConsecutiveOneScan is: " << consecutiveOneScan;


                //This code is helpful in determining where the flag is. Whatever has the higher count (OneScan vs ZeroScan) will be the flag.
                if (consecutiveOneScan>maxOneCount){
                    maxOneCount = consecutiveOneScan;
                }
                //End of commented help code.



                if (consecutiveOneScan == minimumFlagLength) {
                    initSuccess = true;

                }

                if (consecutiveOneScan == maximumFlagLength) {
                    qDebug() << "Error: Roll Initialization failure. Sensor failure - maxFlag threshold exceeded, Voltage too low OR shutter wheel damaged.";
                    data = "Error: Roll Initialization failure. Sensor failure - maxFlag threshold exceeded, Voltage too low OR shutter wheel damaged.";
                    rollInitializeErrorNotifier.sendUpdate(data);
                    emit destroyMotorThreadInitRoll();
                    return;
                }

                moveOneStep(initSpeed, stepPinNegRoll, stepPinPosRoll, motorUsed);
                sensorRead = gpioRead(sensorPinWRoll);
                qDebug() << "sensorRead value IN WHILE is: " << sensorRead;
                //                qDebug() << "sensorReadb value IN WHILE is: " << sensorReadb;

            }

            consecutiveOneScan = 0;


        }

        else { //Sensor doesn't detect and only 0s are returned.
            consecutiveOneScan = 0;
            consecutiveZeroScan++;
            //qDebug() << "ConsecutiveZeroScan is: " << consecutiveZeroScan;

            //This code is helpful in determining where the flag is. The Zero should be the flag but will also have the higher scans hit.
            if (consecutiveZeroScan>maxZeroCount){
                maxZeroCount = consecutiveZeroScan;
            }
            //End of commented help code.

            if (consecutiveZeroScan>=consecutiveZeroThreshold) {
                qDebug() << "Error: Roll Initialization failure. Sensor failure - nothing detected, Voltage too low OR shutter wheel damaged OR GPIO miswiring.";
                data = "Error: Roll Initialization failure. Sensor failure - nothing detected, Voltage too low OR shutter wheel damaged OR GPIO miswiring.";

                rollInitializeErrorNotifier.sendUpdate(data);
                emit destroyMotorThreadInitRoll();
                return;
            }
        }


        moveOneStep(initSpeed, stepPinNegRoll, stepPinPosRoll, motorUsed);

        if (initSuccess) {
            //qDebug() << "initSuccess at end was true. Emitting success";
            emit motorInitializeRollSuccess();
            emit destroyMotorThreadInitRoll();
            return;

        }

    }


    if (!initSuccess) { //main flag not detected after full rotation.
        qDebug() << "Error: Roll Initialization failure. Sensor failure - main flag not detected, Voltage too low OR shutter wheel damaged.";
        data = "Error: Roll Initialization failure. Sensor failure - main flag not detected, Voltage too low OR shutter wheel damaged.";

        rollInitializeErrorNotifier.sendUpdate(data);
        emit destroyMotorThreadInitRoll();
        return;
    }
    emit destroyMotorThreadInitRoll();

}
```

Comment: Please provide your circuit, and a snipet of code showing how you're reading it.

Comment: @Drew Let me know if that works? I had to edit my main post because of the character limits on the comments.

Comment: @dij0nmustard - Hi, You said: "*I had to edit my main post because of the character limits on the comments.*". FYI that is the right thing to do on Stack Exchange. Questions *should* be edited to clarify or add relevant information (unless there has already been a genuine answer attempt, based on the information given at that point, and the planned edit to the question would invalidate that answer - that should be avoided, and can indicate that the question is changing, rather than being clarified).

Answer (score 1):

You must connect the negative side of your external power supply to the RPi Ground.  You may also require pull-up resistors (10K or so) from the Pi input pins to +3.3 Volts.

The inputs will be Low when active.